# Generate SHA256 CSRs PHP Openssl

Tags: php, openssl, sha256

I'm trying to develop some sort of PKI management too with PHP, and I'm finding many issues (partially due documentation) using PHP Openssl.

For example, I learnt via hard way (try-and-error) that PHP openssl doesn't check really for OPENSSL_CONF environment variable, the only real way to use a different config file is to use the $configArray('config' => file_path) argument.

Currently I'm stuck trying to generate a CSR using SHA256 hash method. For the tests I'm using this minimal (but working) openssl.conf configuration:

```
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
[req]
default_md          = sha256
[req_distinguished_name]
[end_req_ext]
keyUsage                = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = serverAuth,clientAuth
```

(note that the 'default_md' setting is overriden by the $configArray['digest_alg'] parameter.

I use this code for testing:

```
$config = array(
    'digest_alg' => "sha256",
    'private_key_bits' => 384,
    'config'    => "/tmp/opensslmy.conf"
);

$dn = array(
    "countryName" => "UK",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "Somerset",
    "localityName" => "Glastonbury",
    "organizationName" => "The Brain Room Limited",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "PHP Documentation Team",
    "commonName" => "Wez Furlong"
);

$key = openssl_pkey_new($config);
if (!$key) {
    print "Error on PKEY_NEW: ".openssl_error_string()."\n";
    exit(1);
}

$csr = openssl_csr_new ( $dn , $key, $config );
$pem = "";
if (openssl_csr_export($csr, $pem)) {
    print $pem."\n";
} else {
    print "Error on CSR_NEW: ".openssl_error_string()."\n";
}
```

It fails:

```
PHP Warning:  openssl_csr_new(): Error signing request in /home/mark/Desktop/ssltest.php on line 25
PHP Warning:  openssl_csr_export() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mark/Desktop/ssltest.php on line 27
Error on CSR_NEW: error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```

If set the initial $config array 'digest_alg' to either md5 or sha1 it works like a charm and succsfully generates a CSR with the given hash algorithm.

I also tried to remove that 'digest_alg' key from the config array and specify it exclusively in the config file (as for my experience I know even for the openssl req -new command, the -sha256 doesn't work and that is the only way to generate sha256 CSRs)

I'm currently using PHP 5.5.9 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.

I'm doing something wrong?
Too old PHP versions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the algorithm, but it's the to small private_key_bits size. This will trigger an error and fails the creation of the CSR.